# Strange IP when trying to yarn start - EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, opensuse

I have a fairly fresh install of OpenSUSE installed on my laptop and was trying to test out a brand new React application.

I ran the following commands from the create-react-app site:

```
    npx create-react-app my-app
    cd my-app
    yarn start
```

When this happens, I get the following output in my terminal

```
yarn run v1.15.2
$ react-scripts start
Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: linux-wjcv
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell

Could not find an open port at linux-wjcv
Network error message:  listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 92.242.140.2

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I confirmed that linux-wjcv is my computer name, but I'm not sure where that 92.242.140.2 IP address is coming from. A quick google search tells me that IP is located in Ireland, which is nowhere near me.

I did a quick look at my hosts file in /etc/hosts and everything I see is going through 127.0.0.1. So I'm not sure where this IP is coming from, or why a fresh application would try to use it.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# special IPv6 addresses
::1         localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0     ipv6-localnet

ff00::0     ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2     ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3     ipv6-allhosts
```

My apologies if this is a dumb question. I'm still pretty new to running a Unix OS.

Comment: If I use "HOST=127.0.0.1 yarn start", it runs on my local server correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your hostname "linux-wjcv" is not defined in the hosts file, so the system tries to lookup its ip addres via DNS. try defining it like this: 
`127.0.0.1   localhost linux-wjcv`